# SQL Server: Trim Character + Integer

Tags: sql-server

Trying to trim the "+1" from the beginning of phone numbers. For example, after running the query I'm pulling: +12223334444 but need 2223334444. I've tried several trim functions but get an error saying "The trim function requires 1 argument(s)".

Sample portion of query:

```
    Select 
    Ef.Name EForm,
    C.Id Contact_Id,
    P.Firstname + ' ' + P.Lastname Agent_Name,
    P.Username Username,
    C.Duration/1000 Call_Duration,
    T.Name Team,
    row_number()over(partition by c.id order by q2.text) Rank,
    rtrim(c.ani,10) calling_number,
    rtrim(c.dnis,10) called_number,
```

Thank you!

Comment: Apologies, believed I figured it out.  Using                                                      ' REPLACE(c.ani,'+1','') Calling_Number,
REPLACE(c.dnis,'+1','') Called_Number, '

Comment: and ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(c.ani,'+1','')) = 1
    and ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(c.dnis,'+1','')) = 1

Answer (score 0):

Call numbers are not Integers, never make that mistake, or numbers may be truncated from their leading zeroes.

Trimming is always related to `space ' '` characters, nothing else.

You can `TRIM('    Hello World   ')` and the result will be `'Hello World'`.

If you want to remove the '+' character, you need to use `REPLACE`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this resolves your initial thought process, but I would probably REPLACE the +1 like you found out.

```
RIGHT(c.ani,10) calling_number, RIGHT(c.dnis,10) called_number
```

Comment: can you guarantee the data will always have the +1? and the last 10 will always be the number? What about International numbers? Just askin...

Comment: Thank you for your responses! Yes, the data will always contain a +1 and last 10 the number so the REPLACE worked perfectly.